Hello, I need help I would like to know how long each lead has been in its current stage
I need help, please. I need to know the time in days that a lead has been in its current state. I have a path with the following stages: "Open," "Working," "Lost," and "Won." I would like to know how long each lead has been in its current stage. Thank you in advance!

In general, questions that show what you've tried so far tend to be received better than those that just list requirements. Even if you're getting an error (especially if you're getting an error) or if it doesn't work the way you want it to, showing us an attempt helps people give more tailored answers. You can [edit] your question to include that.

This isn't something you'll be able to do with a formula field alone. Formulas don't store values, per se, they're recalculated every time you query the record or look at the record detail page. You'll need something like:

A flow or a trigger to look specifically for when the Status/Stage is changing
With a custom field that you can set with the current datetime (when the status/stage does change)

Once you have that custom field set up to store the last time that specific field was changed, and the flow (or Apex trigger, but a flow is probably more appropriate and less daunting here), then you can make a simple formula field like NOW() - That_Custom_Field_You_Made__c to get a decimal like 3.16 where

The integer part is the number of days
The decimal part is fractions of a day. 0.16 => 6 hours and 15 minutes (i.e. 16% of 24 hours)

